# Asp.net login to website is failed in jmeter 2.9

Tags: asp.net, jmeter

First I have added HTTP proxy server and recorded whole login and logout action.
after running script in view result tree, i have selected HTTP(downloaded) but in response data it is displaying an error message to enter your email address and enter your password error.

Please help me to solve this problem.....

Note: Username and password fields are in home page. So, i have to login through home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all try adding a [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan which should be smart enough to deal with sessions and cookies.

I also recall that ASP.NET powered websites require dynamic parameter called VIEWSTATE or something like that. You'll additionally need to add some correlation to your tests, t.w.

- Open Home Page
- Obtain VIEWSTATE value via [Regular Expression Extractor](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) Post Processor and store it to a JMeter Variable, i.e. ASPNET_VIEWSTATE
- Add a corresponding parameter to next request in "Parameters" stanza as VIEWSTATE = ${ASPNET_VIEWSTATE}

Comment: I'm not telepathic enough to guess what's the problem is. If you still need help you could try setting following JMeter Properties: 
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
perhaps some other information like request/response headers, sampler data, etc. should be also saved to simplify analysis. 
and share your .jmx and .jtl files

Elsewise try capturing requests from browser and JMeter via http sniffer like Wireshark and see where and what the differences are.

Comment: An error message it displayed to validate email id and password, but it leads to valid user dashboard. I had verified with more than 1 user using user parameters with PreProcessor. Do you have any solution to prevent error message. Thank You for your support!!

Comment: If you're reaching out to user dashboard I guess that authentication went well. Are you sure that error message is really "displayed"? Perhaps it's just present in page source code and is not visible due to having "display: none" CSS class or whatever?

Comment: Login sampler is passed. But that Login error message are displayed in Home page, Login page and after logout again in home page in Response data of view result tree.